# How to access mysql databases from inaccessible virtual machine

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I used to log into a server and then from there into a virtual machine to do my daily business. However the VM has now become non-responsive, and I am stuck unable to access my databases on it.

Is there a way to locate and copy my mysql database tables from the VM? FYI I am running Ubuntu linux. And I just have a guest account on this machine, without root privileges, and the sys admin is on break.

Comment: I was just thinking of this - can i search the file system of my VM for files containing specific strings that I know occur in my database? I tried doing that but the results returned nothing !!

Comment: And just FYI, the command that I used to search the entire file system is ' grep -r "STRING" '. Linux noob here.

Comment: Hi folks, any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the VM at all? Even over SSH?

What format is the virtual machine's disk? (vmdk etc)

Comment: Yep. SSH gives me unreachable host error. That's exactly how I access it. How do I find out the format of VM's disk?